# Swift error with new xcode ' static properties are only allowed within structs and enums; use class. property'

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I am getting the error on the following line.

```
static let sharedData : SharedData = SharedData()
```

I am using the new Xcode (6.2) so I don't know why I am getting this error. I thought this should've worked. Please let me know how to resolve this issue. Perhaps I should be using a different version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, static properties aren't yet allowed inside a class. (What is more, `class` is the keyword used to create static properties) Here is a work around for you to create static variables:

```
private struct SubStruct { static var sharedData:SharedData?}

class var sharedData:SharedData? {
    get { return SubStruct.sharedData }
    set { SubStruct.sharedData = newValue }
}
```

You can now refer the static variable as `YourClass.sharedData`.